# How do I reference an Excel workbook that is on located on a network

Tags: excel, vba

The network path of my workbook is:
\\Consumershare.nam.net\sites\DRMGT\Dashboards\10-10-2017\Dashboard.xlsx

My code below copies columns from one workbook to another. But when I replace my source workbook(sourceTitle) with the network path it throws an error(Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range). Do I need to know the server and/or drive it is located in? Or does my local Windows credentials need rights to the location?

```
Sub T1()
Dim sourceTitle As Range, targetTitle As Range

Set sourceTitle = Workbooks("Director Release Dashboard 
10102017.xlsx").Worksheets(2).Columns("B")
Set targetTitle = Workbooks("Dashboard 101317 - 
Copy2.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")

sourceTitle.Copy Destination:=targetTitle

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to have both workbooks *open* to be able to copy / paste ranges. So, open the workbook from the network first, then preform range declarations and copy / paste

Comment: To further on @ScottHoltzman's comment, try `dim sourceWB as workbook` and `set sourceWB = workbooks.open(sourcePath)` with sourcePath being the full path & filename for the source file.